# AngularJS: homeController is not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is **app.states.js**:

```
angular.module('fuelComparatorApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');
        $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'app/components/home/views/home.view.html',
                controller: "homeController",
                controllerAs: 'ctrl'
            })
            .state('404', {
                url: '/404',
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/404.html'
            });
    }]);
```

And this is **home.services.js**:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('fuelComparatorApp.homeServices', []).service('sayHelloService', sayHelloService);
    sayHelloService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

    function sayHelloService() {
        function sayHi() {
            console.log("hi from home service");
        }
    }
})();
```

**home.controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('fuelComparatorApp').controller('homeController', homeController);
    homeController.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$window", "$q", "sayHelloService"];

    function homeController($scope, $http, $window, $q, sayHelloService) {
        const vm = this;
        vm.fuelComparatorService = sayHelloService;
        sayHelloService;
        return vm;
    }
})();
```

Inside the index.html there is the usual `ng-app="fuelComparatorApp"` and home.view.html which utilises `ng-controller="homeController"` directive.

There are no errors, just the index.html doesn't show a anything from home.view.html as if I missed something somewhere.

Comment: could u plz paste in Jsfiddler

Comment: @MDGosoddin I am not very good with JSFiddle, but here goes: https://jsfiddle.net/makdeniss/xfL80ora/#&togetherjs=HDaeCnk8fN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this was missing from the index.html

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

This is specific to ui-router.